# Liquibase not able to complete execution of changeLog file

Tags: postgresql, liquibase

I am currently using Liquibase Version 4.23.0 running on Ubuntu version 22.04.2 LTS.

I am trying to deploy changes to my postgreSQL database version 14.8.  The changelog has about 6 deployment id' that create three different tables in the same schema. The update sucessfully create two of the tables in the changeLog, but in the last table I get the following error:

> Running Changeset:
> modules/2023-01/features/RDB-0050-Create_schema_auth.sql::5::gabriel.lobo-blanco
>
> Unexpected error running Liquibase: Error executing SQL SELECT
> MAX(ORDEREXECUTED) FROM public.databasechangelog: ERROR: permission
> denied for table databasechangelog

The script completes the deployment of the first two tables and makes the proper updates to both `DATABASECHANGELOG` and `DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK` tables.  I have removed the md5 check sums from the tables and the scripts puts them again without any issues. I have also removed the lock on the `DATAQBASECAHNGELOGLOCK` table using various methods and the execution lock it again but fails to remove the lock again.

Has anyone else run into this issues? How was it resolved?

I have removed the md5 check sums from the tables and the scripts puts them again without any issues. I have also removed the lock on the `DATAQBASECAHNGELOGLOCK` table using various methods and the execution lock it again but fails to remove the lock again.